# DynamoDb Validation Error 400 Bad request

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services

I've been scratching my head over this one for a while. Does anyone see where the issue is:

Code:

```
x=None
y=None
split = key.split("/")
if ".svg" in loc:
    svgF=open(loc,"r").read()
    svg = etree.fromstring(svgF)
    x = svg.xpath("//@width")[0]
    x=x[:x.__len__()-4]
    y = svg.xpath("//@height")[0]
    y=y[:y.__len__()-4]
elif ".swf" not in loc:
    i=Image.open(loc)
    dim = i.size
    x=dim[0]
    y=dim[1]
data={}
data["x"]=x
data["y"]=y
data["primary color"]="none"
data["secondary color"]= "none"
data["tertiary color"]="none"
data["time"]=str(getTimeAsInt)
data["parent"]=split[1]+split[2]

newI = imageTable.new_item(split[1]+split[2]+split[11],"image", data)
#try:
newI.save()
return(split[1]+split[2]+split[11])
#except:
#    pass
split[1]+split[2]+split[11]
```

Error:

> File "/Users/tai/Documents/workspace/testSelenium/testS/database.py", line 188, in recursiveInnerFile
>       dynamoStorage.saveImage(loc,key)
>     File "/Users/tai/Documents/workspace/testSelenium/testS/dynamoStorage.py", line 161, in saveImage
>       newI.save()
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/boto/dynamodb/item.py", line 141, in save
>       return_values)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/boto/dynamodb/layer2.py", line 592, in update_item
>       object_hook=self.dynamizer.decode)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/boto/dynamodb/layer1.py", line 425, in update_item
>       object_hook=object_hook)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/boto/dynamodb/layer1.py", line 119, in make_request
>       retry_handler=self._retry_handler)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/boto/connection.py", line 932, in _mexe
>       status = retry_handler(response, i, next_sleep)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/boto/dynamodb/layer1.py", line 156, in _retry_handler
>       response.status, response.reason, data)
>   boto.dynamodb.exceptions.DynamoDBValidationError: DynamoDBValidationError: 400 Bad Request
>   {u'message': u'One or more parameter values were invalid: Only DELETE action is allowed when no attribute value is specified', u'__type': u'com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException'}

When I change this line like this:

```
 newI = imageTable.new_item(data["parent"], data)
```

I do not get an error however the information is not stored in dynamo correctly. I only get the ID and no other columns.

Additionally for my text which is set up very similarly this works fine:

```
        newI = textTable.new_item(split[1]+split[2]+split[11],item_data["time"], item_data)
```

text code:

```
#TODO this will not work ID is unique only for the swf, not for the text file, it will need each   text
def createText(loc,theNewKey):
with open(loc, "r") as myfile:
    item_data={}
    item_data["time"] = int(getTimeAsInt())
    theText=""
    inText=False
    count = 0;
    split = theNewKey.split("/")
    for line in myfile:
        if line.__len__() >3:
            #if the line starts with text
            if line[0]=="]" and line[1] !="[":
                if("[" in line):
                    line=re.sub("[\]\[]","",line)
                    inText= False;
                    item_data["display_text"+str(count)]=""
                    item_data["display_text"+str(count)] = item_data["display_text"+str(count)] + " " + line[0:line.__len__()]
                    count+=1
                    #if the line does not end the next line will also contain text
                else:
                    line=re.sub("[\]]","",line)
                    inText=True
                    #for some reason adding this line fixes the concatenation issue
                    item_data["display_text"+str(count)]=""
                    item_data["display_text"+str(count)] = item_data["display_text"+str(count)] + " " + line[0:line.__len__()]
                theText+=" " + line
            elif line is not None and inText is False:
                splitL= line.split(" ");
                if splitL is not None and splitL.__len__()>=2:
                    place = splitL[0]
                    item_data[place+str(count)]=splitL[1]
            elif inText:
                if("[" in line):
                    inText=False
                    re.sub("\]\[","",line)
                    item_data["display_text"+str(count)]+=" "+line
                    count+=1
                else:
                    re.sub("\]\[","",line)
                    item_data["display_text"+str(count)]+=" "+line
                theText+=" " + line
        elif("[" in line):
            if inText:
                inText = False
                count+=1
    item_data["parent"]=split[1]+split[2]
    newI = textTable.new_item(split[1]+split[2]+split[11],item_data["time"], item_data)
    try:
        newI.save()
        return(split[1]+split[2]+split[11])
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: What is `key`? What type is `imageTable`? I get what you're trying to do, but without seeing how your `new_item` method works and what your DB schema looks like, it's difficult to say where the error is.

Comment: key is the same as myNewKey in the working function. Image table doesn't have a type (not sure)